# PHP Multiple File Upload Script Failing Without Message

Tags: php, html

I'm using the following form to upload multiple files (using HTML5's new support for multiple file selection):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="upload-script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload files below:<br />
    <input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" required="required" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This form handles the file uploads and uses `upload-script.php` to process them. That code is as follows:

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);$i++)
{
    if ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"][$i] > 0)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["userfile"]["error"][$i] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$i] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["userfile"]["type"][$i] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"][$i] / 1024) . " kB<br />";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$i];
    }
    rename($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$i] , "storage/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$i]);
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

For 2 or 3 files, this works perfectly (the info is displayed as indicated), but for many more files (testing with approximately 32), the page loads but displays nothing. I'm not sure what error is occurring. I just get a blank screen on upload-script.php. What might be happening here?

Comment: Check the error log ?

Comment: I don't have access to the error log directly on my server...is there another way to get to it?

Comment: You don't know where it is, or you don't have enough permissions to read it?

Comment: Also how big are the files you are trying to send. I think php has limit on upload filesize. That's a total not per file.

Comment: I've looked up where it is, and I don't believe I have access to the directories that contain the error log. But I could be wrong, would you know where it is?
I'm now looking into adjusting those max total upload sizes, but how high can they go? I'm not too certain about how big it should be at the current time...

Comment: Could it also be timing out? (see php max execution time).

Comment: When I sent it to the client, they said it was "timing out right away" but that seemed odd (since "immediately" is a very short timespan in which to time out). So I've now set the max input time as follows: `ini_set('max_input_time', 123456);` and I've set the max execution time as follows: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 123456);`